# Cannot see added UIScrollView in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I added a `UIScrollView` to my main `UIViewController` but for some reason i can't see anything. I painted the scroll view in grey in order to see the actual size, but all i get is a white screen.

Here is my very simple code:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIScrollView *scroll;
[scroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];


CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
_orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(_orientation)){
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
}else{
    scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
}

scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenRect.origin.x,
                                                        screenRect.origin.y,
                                                        screenRect.size.width,
                                                        screenRect.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
}
```

The view size might change, i'm working on a changing iOS device size.

Comment: `scroll` is `nil` when you set the background color. Initialize it when you declare it.

Comment: @RichTolley thanks man, can't believe i missed that.
Mind writing it as an answer so that i would be able to close this?